# How to convert a vector to a euler angle

Tags: javascript, vector, trigonometry, angle, euler-angles

I've scoured the net for almost three hours in an attempt to find the answer to my question. I have read [articles](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/rotation_2d.html) and watched many [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zewLu4_Bp0) that show how to get a vector's angle in degrees or radians. But that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

I suspect I may not know the correct words to describe what I'm trying to do, so I decided to draw it.
[image]

In essence, I'm trying to write a simple function that takes a 2D vector as input ([3,1] in my example) and returns what I think is called a euler angle. In my example the output would be around 290. The vector could have negative coordinates, for instance [-3, -1] would output around 110.

I don't know if this changes anything but negative outputs are also acceptable. For instance, instead of 270, -90 would be a corresponding acceptable output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the angle from x-axis counterclockwise is invert tangent of `y/x` you just need to have result in degrees, increase it by 270 keeping angles domain in [0,360) like that:

```
function euler_angle(x,y) { 
    var rad = Math.atan(y/x);   // arcus tangent in radians
    var deg = rad*180/Math.PI;  // converted to degrees
    if (x<0) deg += 180;        // fixed mirrored angle of arctan
    var eul = (270+deg)%360;    // folded to [0,360) domain
    return eul;
}
```

Comment: Great! Seems like a pretty simple solution. Just so I get a better grasp of what is going on here, could you explain what would need to change in your solution if, let's say, the coordinates system was inverted on the x axis? Or if the degrees were clockwise instead of counter-clockwise?

Comment: What do you mean by _"inverted on the x axis"_? Mirror about y-axis (left side swap with right side) or about x-axis (top swap with bottom)?

Comment: Mirror about y-axis(left side swap with right side). In my example, (3,1) would be (-3,1).

Comment: Well, basic idea would remain. In simplest way it would be `360-euler_angle(x,y)`, where euler_angle is current implementation. Changing reference points (rotating, mirroring etc) changes subsequent ingredients, there is no meta rule. If you want to get really generic approach then dig into matrix transformations of vectors heavily used in 3D graphics.